# Como usar funcion map() de laravel-excel 3.1 desde un array

Tags: laravel

estoy intentando exportar ciertos datos con la libreria laravel-excel, hace poco implemente la suma de cierta columna, por lo que tuve que hacer uso de `FromArray`:

```
class SalesExport implements FromArray, WithMapping, WithHeadings, WithColumnFormatting, ShouldAutoSize
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */

    protected $sales;
    // protected $indicatorService;

    public function __construct($sales){
        $this->sales = $sales;
    }
    public function array(): array
    {
        $count = count($this->sales) +1; // count of records
        foreach($this->sales as $row)
        {
            // dd($row);
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
        array_push($arr,['Total:','', '' ,'=SUM(D2:D'.$count.')','', '']);
        return [
            'values' => $arr
        ];
    }
```

todo bien, pero los datos los estoy extrayendo desde una consulta con eloquent y me estan trayendo datos que no necesito (como las id), segun la documentacion de esta libreria puedo usar la funcion map() e indicar que atributos quiero usar, pero como hago esto si estoy usando fromArray()?, intente algo asi:

```
public function map($arr): array
    {
        return [
            $arr['name'],
            $arr['price'],
            $arr['name'],
            $arr['totalcantidad'],
            $arr['totalrecaudado']
            
        ];
    }
```

Pero no me dio resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nose que versión de php está usando pero puedes usar **array_map**,el funcionamiento sería:

```
<?php
function data($arr)
{
        return [
        $arr['name'],
        $arr['price'],
        $arr['name'],
        $arr['totalcantidad'],
        $arr['totalrecaudado']
        
    ];
}

$data_final = array_map("data", $arr);
print_r($data_final);
?>
```

Te dejo el enlace a la docu del método:https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php

Otra opción sería castear tu resultado a collection:

```
$collection = collect($arr)->map(function ($data) {
        return [
        $data['name'],
        $data['price'],
        $data['name'],
        $data['totalcantidad'],
        $data['totalrecaudado']
        
    ];;
})->reject(function ($data) {
    return empty($data);
});
```

Le dejo el link aqui https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections.Espero que le sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilice array_map()